# right shift for float

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I have float var like that

```
float f = 0b 00000000 11110001 00000000 00000000
```

I want to take 1st(not 0st) byte to char variable.
I can't do << and >>.
how can i do that?

Comment: Independent on the shifting of floating point numbers: I guess that "0b ..." is a binary integral constant. I can't tell for sure because it doesn't seem to be part of C++. However, if that is so please not that the bit pattern stored in the floating point variable will be different. Typically, floating point numbers are representing using IEEE-754 (or something reasonably similar) and bit pattern would shift all bits up, chopping off the leading [implicit] digit, and add an exponent. I really question that what you try to do is what you want to do...

Answer (score 3):

There is generally little point messing with the binary representation of floating point values. Any you'll try will not be portable. However, generally, these two work:

```
char c(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f)[1]);
union {
    float f;
    char  c[sizeof(float)];
} u = { f };
u.c[1];
```

Comment: <code>float m = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;char c = 0;
c = *( (char *)(&m) + 1);
cout << int(c) << endl;</pre> and i have 0, wtf?</code>

Comment: I don't have a computer to quickly teat but the 0b111... is an integer which can't be represented exactly as float. How the representation looks like I don't know off-hand but is likely that it got rounded to the nearest power of 2. This would be represented with all zeros (the leading 1 is implicit) except for the exponent which would be `32 - bias` (don't know float's biss off-hand either).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I thought accessing a union out of order is unspecified. Admittedly, I haven't paid a lot attention to whether this stuff is changing but I couldn't locate a quote in the standard backing up either statement: can you point me at the section where this is described?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: It follows in some roundabout way from 9.5 on unions: At most one member can be active at any time, and the union behaves like that were the only member.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, I saw this statement but this doesn't imply _undefined_ behavior from what I can see. I'm pretty sure that in C++2003 is said _unspecified_ behavior and there is a lot code around which uses this `union` approach to convert between types, e.g. between an array of scalar types and an SIMD value of the corresponding type.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Hm, I'm suddenly thinking of a million flies, but I don't quite know why...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sure, just because everybody is doing it it neither means it is defined nor that it should be defined. However, changing something from unspecified to undefined could be seen as an unnecessary big leap. On the other, the behavior wasn't portable before, it isn't portable afterwards, and still works the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
char bla;
bla = *((char *) &f + 1)
```

Also remember that with endianness, on little endian systems what you may actually want is byte 2 (assuming you count your byte from 0 to 3). In that case you would change the `+ 1` with `+ 2` in the code above.

Comment: It should be noted that this code depends on the endianness of the platform.

Comment: this recipe works sooo strange, i have float = 1 and using ...+1 or +2 i can get 63 or -128

Comment: @AntonyTren'kin: You really need to develop a bit of an understanding for the IEEE754 float representation before you allow wonder to overwhelm you.